# Palindromes in a Statement: Java

Tags: java, string, palindrome

I need some help with a palindrome detector that I am doing for homework. I need the user to enter a statement, so more then one word, and the program needs to detect which words are a palindrome and which ones are not. However, something in my loop is going wrong in that, it will only detect the first word then blend the others after together. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
   static int numpali = 0;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // ask the user to enter a statement
      String statement = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Statement");
      String reverse = "";
      // Array to split the sentence
      String[] words = statement.split(" ");

      // Run a loop to seperate the words in the statement into single Strings
      for (String word : words) {
         // Print out original word
         System.out.println(word + "\n");
         int wordlength = word.length();
         // send the word to lowercase so capitals are negligible
         String wordlower = word.toLowerCase();

         // Run a loop that reverses each individual word to see if its a
         // palindrome
         for (int t = wordlength; t > 0; t--) {
            reverse += wordlower.substring(t - 1, wordlength);
            wordlength--;
         }
         System.out.println(reverse);
         // show a message if the word is a palindrome or not, and add 1 to the
         // total number of palindromes
         if (reverse.equals(wordlower)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + " is a Palindrome!");
            numpali = numpali + 1;
         }
         word = "";
      }
      System.out.println("Number of Palindromes:" + "\n" + numpali);
   }
}
```

I've tried to explain what its doing the best I can inside the program.

Comment: Your code formatting is terrible making your code very difficult to read. You've asked questions here before, so you should already know this, but when posting code to the forum, we appreciate it if you put some effort in towards making your code as well formatted and readable as possible. After all, you're asking volunteers to read, understand your code and help you, and so this really isn't asking too much.

Comment: you are not clearing `reverse` at the start of the loop.

Comment: rule of thumb, chuck it in eclipse, highlight, ctrl-shift-f

Comment: Apologies if it was bad formatting, I didn't really think it was in all honesty. I spaced it out more so its not so bunched up, is this a bit better? Just so I know for next time :)

Comment: @Dave555: please read up on proper Java code formatting, something I'm sure you can easily find with a simple Google search, and look at some examples of good formatting that you can see on this site. The key is uniformity and adherence to standards. If you adhere to these, it is *much* easier to understand your code and thus your question. The main problem with your currently posted code is that your indentation style is almost the opposite of what it should be.

Comment: For example, see the changes I've made to your posted code, in particular with the indentation. One key change being that all lines in the same block of code is indented exactly the same.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. Its the indentation when I place a nested loop and the code within those loops. I'll be sure to make future posts more readable in that regard. Thanks for being patient with me (I hope I'm not being too much of a nuisance), I really do appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never reset the "reverse" value inside your loop. So after the first word your just adding more characters to "reverse" every iteration.

Put

```
reverse = "";
```

inside your main for loop

Comment: To add to this: You clear the variable word at the end of the loop, so I think you just got the two mixed up. Just replace word = "" with reverse = "".

Comment: Okay I see what I did wrong, I thought it was the original variable that was causing it. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Reset the value of reverse to reverse=""; just like what you have done word="";